# How to capture a nested HTML element?

Tags: html, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am trying to capture a HTML element, for the purpose of sending the value into GA as an event. I am using GTM, and want to use a click trigger to push this HTML value into a variable.

For example, the tags are set up like this:

```
<div class ="xxxyyyyzzzz" value1="qwejsdkfj" value3="akhdfjksh">
    <div class ="fjk" >
        <h1> "xyz2"</h1>
```

with each level nested under the other. The value we want to capture for GTM purposes is the one that sits under h1 ("xyz2"). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select the value in JS and transmit it to GA via event (or the initial pageview, if you want to hold the number of requests low).

Method without GTM:

Select the value of your HTML tag via selector

```
// select the value via CSS selector, catch the first result of your query
var selector = document.querySelectorAll(".fjk h1")[0];

// select your category, action and label (I set label with the value of your selector
if(selector) ga('send', 'event', [eventCategory], [eventAction], selector, [eventValue], [fieldsObject]);
```

Method within GTM:

Create a variable which holds the information of your HTML tag. Use "CSS Selector" in variable definition and use the CSS selector I mentioned above.

Use the variable within your Universal Analytics Tag definition. You can set the value of a custom dimension index with the value of your defined variable.